# Android-facebook Message

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know is there any way to send a message to a friend in facebook from an android app.(Not wall post).Googled a lot about this topic but didn't get any proper solution.Guide me to some reference or blog

Comment: See: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2943297/how-send-message-facebook-friend-through-graph-api-using-accessstoken

Comment: Hi thanks 4 answering...i have already go thru those

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about native application but you can do it from HTML5 application using javascript:-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

If no other solution place the script in an html file and load the same from the native app

Comment: mm....i just started doing like that...thanks 4 answering ..but is there any workaround other than this one??